# The meaning\reading of 急停止集団巣鴨?

Tags: kanji, readings

**Context:** The title of  [This video by Megwin](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPpMH1GJy5E&feature=g-u-u).

The title of the video is:

> トゲ抜き老人が腰抜かす!?急停止集団巣鴨に現る

The second part is confusing me.
Too many kanji in a row for me. I understand it's probably a name, but google gave no results and I have no idea how to even try translating it or searching for it's reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps because it is a title, there is high degree of omission.

The full sentence could be 急停止する集団が[巣鴨]{すがも}に現れる。It means "flash mob appears at [巣鴨(a place in Japan)](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B7%A3%E9%B4%A8)".

Probably worth noting is that "flash mob" is not a one-to-one translation of "急停止集団", but it gets the meaning across. 急停止 would mean "sudden stop" and 急停止集団 would be "a group of people that stops suddenly".

Comment: Ohh I see. This makes perfect sense now.
I guess being able to seperate the kanji into words like that in your mind is a matter of experience huh... Thank you!